# Spalsh screen Time duration

Tags: mobile

We build an application for mobile app in salesforce.. when we login into app intially we setup the splash screen from salesforce branding ..but when we launch app we are unable to see splash screen ..I want to increase the splash screen time duration for 1 mint so that I can see spalsh screen in your mobile

Comment: Android? iOS? Windows? What platform are you developing for?

Comment: Android and IOS.

Comment: We are building an application in Salesforce with lightning framework. I don't think it related to Android/iPhone/windows ... Just we want splash screen to appear after when we enter credentials of Salesforce .. right now we are unable to seen the spalsh screen even we done with configuration.. if I increase time duration of spalsh screen then u would able to seen the splash screen in salesforce